# Partial Sobolev function: if $f(x,y) \in W^{1,1}((0,1)\times (0,1))$ and $\partial_{x}f(x,y) = 0$, there is $h(y) \in L^1(0,1)$ s.t. $f(x,y) = h(y)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $f: (0,1)\times (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $$f(x,y) \in W^{1,1}((0,1)\times (0,1))$$ and $$\partial_{x}f(x,y) = 0 \quad \text{ a.e. (weak derivative).}$$

How do I prove that there exists a function $$h(y) \in L^1(0,1)$$ such that $$f(x,y) = h(y)$$ for a.e. $(x,y) \in (0,1)\times(0,1)$?

This should be trivially true if $f$ is regular, but why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the usual approximation $f_\varepsilon \to f$ in $L^1((0,1)^2)$, where $f_\varepsilon$ are smooth functions obtained by convolution: $f_\varepsilon = f * \varphi_\varepsilon$.

The classical derivative $\partial_x f_\varepsilon$ exists and equals $f * \partial_x \varphi_\varepsilon$. By the definition of the weak derivative, this equals $\partial_x f * \varphi_\varepsilon$ (for points $p \in (0,1)^2$ with $\operatorname{dist}(p,\partial (0,1)^2) > \varepsilon$). We know that $\partial_x f \equiv 0$, so also $\partial_x f_\varepsilon \equiv 0$. But $f_\varepsilon$ is smooth, so we infer that $f_\varepsilon$ doesn't depend on the $x$ variable.

Consider the subspace of such functions: 
$$ V := \{ g \in L^1((0,1)^2) : g(x,y) = h(y) \text{ for some } h \in L^1(0,1) \} $$
It is easily seen that $V$ is complete (as it's isometric with $L^1((0,1))$) and hence a closed subspace of $L^1((0,1)^2)$. Since $f_\varepsilon \in V$ and $f_\varepsilon \to f$ in $L^1((0,1)^2)$, we also have $f \in V$.

---

The above reasoning has a little flaw: $f * \partial_x \varphi_\varepsilon = \partial_x f * \varphi_\varepsilon$ doesn't work for points close to the boundary. We can bypass it by taking a smaller domain $U_\delta = (-1+\delta,1-\delta)^2$ and considering only $\varepsilon < \delta$. Then we get that $f|_{U_\delta}$ doesn't depend on the $x$ variable. Taking all possible values of $\delta > 0$, we obtain the claim for $(-1,1)^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate on "It is easily seen that $V$ is complete (as it's isometric with $L^1((0,1))$) and hence a closed subspace of $L^1((0,1)^2)$."?

Comment: @Riku Just map each function $h \in L^1((0,1))$ to $g \in V$ defined by $g(x,y) = h(y)$. This is an isometry.

Comment: Why is that? And why does this imply that $V$ is closed?

Comment: @Riku If you write down the definition of the norm in each space, there is really nothing to prove. As for the latter question, if $V \subseteq W$ is a linear subspace of Banach space $W$, then $V$ is closed in $W$ iff it's complete.